# ORA-00936 Missing EXPRESSION error when WHERE clause is used

Tags: c#, oracle

I have a query ending with a where clause:

```
WHERE       C.CUSTOMER_ID   IN (@CustomerID)";
```

My OracleDataAdapter contains this line:

```
oracleDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("@CustomerID", OracleDbType.NVarchar2)).Value = (string)args["CustomerID"];
```

CustomerID = 00000081

For filling the DataTable I have...

```
oracleDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
```

Unfortunately it is also here where it throws the `ORA-00936 Missing EXPRESSION error`
When I remove the where clause it run perfectly.

Any idea what is wrong with my where clause or parameter definition?

Comment: bind variables for Oracle typically start with `:` and not with `@`

Comment: Does query work if you use Native Oracle Tools?  Trying to determine if the query is bad or there is issues in the Driver (part of connection string).  Are you using a Oracle driver or another vendor driver.  Oracles errors are common when you do not use an Oracle driver or the driver and the version of Oracle are not the same.

Comment: `WHERE       C.CUSTOMER_ID   IN (:CustomerID)";`, note `:` (column) instead of `@`. Same for the parameter creation: `new OracleParameter(":CustomerID", ...`